# PHP File upload, working fine on one machine but not on other?

Tags: php, file-upload

While I was trying to uplaod file using php on windows machine its working fine :

```
   <form action="php/bulk.php"
  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <p>
   Please specify a file below:<br>
  </p>
    <div>
  <input id="datafile" type="file" name="datafile" size="40"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
 </div></form>
```

code on bulk.php :

```
$connector = new DbConnector();
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['datafile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datafile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['datafile']['name']).
  " has been uploaded.  \n";

} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
?>
<form action="../addsamples.php">
 <input type="submit" value="Go Back" />
</form>
<?php
    exit (-1);
}
```

I tried uploading on server and its not working there ! Do Operating system play any role in this ? My server is red hat linux and test m/c is windows

Comment: Have you set the correct write permissions on the folder you're trying to upload to?

Comment: Your PHP configuration could easily play a role in this.  There's a limit to the size of files uploaded that is set in the configuration.  That would be the first place to check.  How big is the file you are attempting to upload?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Define what you mean by "not working".

Comment: Its not giving any written errors in specific. Error that I have echoed as "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!". that`s it.

Comment: File size I am trying to uplaod is 412 KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem is the file-permissions. Does the user that is running the web-server (`apache` I think for red hat) have write-permissions for `php/uploads/`?

Comment: It was a permission problem. Thank you very much !